# Chd 5.4.0 issues with map and reduce

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, cloudera

I have a problem when I'm executing a simple query (something like select * from tablex) in Hive always show

Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%

I tried to execute that query using beeline and HUE in both cases got the same situation.

can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be because of the following reasons

1. Your cluster is not having enough resources to launch a container.
2. Your job is submitted to a resource pool or queue without proper resources.

Check the total resources in the cluster. If enough resources are available, check the queue in which the job got submitted and check the resources allocated to that queue.

These details can be checked from the resource manager UI.

Answer (score 0):

the issues was reported to cloudera https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-11502